# Does the Logitech Extreme 3D Pro work with Windows 10 metro app games?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Logitech Extreme 3D Pro plugged in and the Logitech Profile v5.10.127 (the latest version of software for this device) running. I have a profile mapped out for Asphalt 8: Airborn, the title I wanted to test it with. After setting all the button mappings and the location of the executable, the software seems to be unaware that the game is running.

Can I not use this device with any of the metro games with Windows 10, despite being was essentially breaks down to a keymapper?